# grunt-php task springing open multiple browser instances

Tags: gruntjs

I'm building a Gruntfile.js.
I'm trying to create tasks for responding to php requests.

Other tasks include live compiling compass/sass and live-reload.
I've hit an interesting snag:

When I start grunt, I can see in the terminal that the watch tasks is running, and that the php server is running: I get messages in terminal about certain files not being in place.

Now heres the thing... a couple of seconds after I start grunt, firefox windows start opening. (I start the task without firefox running at all. I generally use chromium and chrome).

New windows keep opening. ff messages about firefox crashing sometimes pop up. I also get windows popping up telling me that my ff profile is inaccessible - which is what I'd expect if I try and run 'firefox' from the terminal while ff is already running.

They keep popping up until I stop grunt from running. They all close immediately when I stop the task, by Ctrl-c from the terminal.

What could be causing this?

Here is my gruntfile

```
module.exports = function (grunt){
grunt.initConfig({

    compass : {
        dist : {
            options : {
                cssDir : 'css',
                sassDir : 'sass',
                debugInfo : true
            }
        }
    },

php :{      
    dist : { 
    options : {
        keepalive : true,
        port: 9000
    }
    },
    watch : {
    files : ['*.html',  '*.php',  'js/*', 'sass/*', 'css/*'],
    tasks : ['compass'],
    options : {
                livereload: true
    }
        }           
},      

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-php');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');    
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');   
grunt.registerTask('default', ['php', 'watch']) ;

} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `watch` task specifies that you want to use `livereload` - so, that's (kind of) expected, right?

See here:

- https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload
- http://livereload.com/

Comment: Not really, no. I've created watch tasks that invoke livereload before and I've never expected or seen this behaviour. I don't think that livereload is intended to pop open a zillion browser windows.

Comment: Agreed. Still, what happens if you remove livereload from your watch options? Depending on the result, can you simplify your test case so that the (apparently) bug in watch / livereload is easier to reproduce?

Comment: Put otherwise: it looks to me like firefox / livereload is misconfigured - or that watch is doing something nasty with livereload.